# tortoisesvn commit with * seperated paths taking over 8GB of memory and stalling computer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I have a batch file to commit folders to SVN, as per below:

```
tortoiseproc /command:commit /path:"path1*path2*path3" /closeonend:3
```

If I execute the above command, the spawned process starts taking loads of memory until the computer hangs - Over 8GB.

If I split the command into 3 seperate commands, as per below - it works fine:

```
tortoiseproc /command:commit /path:"path1" /closeonend:3
tortoiseproc /command:commit /path:"path2" /closeonend:3
tortoiseproc /command:commit /path:"path3" /closeonend:3
```

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Why do you run tortoiseproc instead of a command-line svn.exe client? BTW, you may want to report this to users@ TortoiseSVN mailing list to get better answer about this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is [known and already fixed](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/issues/detail?id=661). Try a nightly build.